# History For Private Data In Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Is there any way to get the history for Private data in Hyperledger Fabric node SDK.
I've tried using `getHistoryForKey(key)`

It returns an empty object with only `{ done: true }`

Answer (score 4):

The API to get history for private data is not yet implemented, but is planned for a future release of Hyperledger Fabric.

In the interim you could add some minimal information to a public key in the same transaction for historical tracking. That could either be a logical key, or if the key itself is sensitive, you could take a hash of the logical key and save that as a public key. Then use GetHistoryForKey on the public key to find the transactions of the private data.