# Question regarding Private Data Collection

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am currently working on hyper ledger fabric version 1.3 and using private data collections in one of my projects.

I have one scenario in which I need to find out the history of all txns done on a particular asset and not able to do that. We have the below chain code API available to get a history of a key which gets committed in world state :

```
stub.GetHistoryForKey(key)
```

Do we have something like this available for private assets also ?? I would really appreciate if someone could guide me for achieving this functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you can do this [using composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783822/historian-for-a-particular-participant), but not natively in Fabric.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [History For Private Data In Hyperledger Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51960671/history-for-private-data-in-hyperledger-fabric)
, so, i think it is not implemented in 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

The API to get history for private data is not yet implemented, but is planned for a future release of Hyperledger Fabric.

In the interim you could add some minimal information to a public key in the same transaction for historical tracking. That could either be a logical key, or if the key itself is sensitive, you could take a hash of the logical key and save that as a public key. Then use GetHistoryForKey on the public key to find the transactions of the private data.